# How to print only last value from the loop

Tags: java

Currently console prints all the values from the loop, but there is needed to print only the last one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int PeopleQty = scanner.nextInt();
        int PiecesQty = scanner.nextInt();
        int PizzaQty = 1;
        boolean divisibleByPieces = false;
        while (!divisibleByPieces) {
            System.out.println(PizzaQty);
            if ((PiecesQty * PizzaQty) % PeopleQty == 0)
                divisibleByPieces = true;
            ++PizzaQty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `System.out.println(PizzaQty);` from inside the loop to after the loop?

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names, which start in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Simply move the print statement after the loop:

```java
while (!divisibleByPieces) {
    if ((PiecesQty * PizzaQty) % PeopleQty == 0) {
        divisibleByPieces = true;
        ++PizzaQty;
    }
}
System.out.println(PizzaQty);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!divisibleByPieces) {
           // System.out.println(PizzaQty); //move this print to outside of loop
            if ((PiecesQty * PizzaQty) % PeopleQty == 0)
                divisibleByPieces = true;
            ++PizzaQty;
        }
System.out.println(PizzaQty);
```